# Rails OCI8 protecting from injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, sql-injection, oci8

I am building a webform which I want to prepopulate with data from an external oracle database. We are using the rails OCI8 plug in.

I want to ensure that I am not leaving myself open to injection by using the URL parameters directly in the query.

For example in the controller:

```
  def new
    if params[:provider] && u = findByUserName(params[:provider])
        monkey = {
            :employeeEmail => u['EMAIL_ADDRESS'],
            :employeeFirst => u['FIRST_NAME'],
            :employeeLast => u['LAST_NAME'],
            :userID => u['LOGIN_ID'],
            :supervisorUserID => u['SUPERVISOR_ID'],
            :supervisorName => u['SUPERVISOR_NAME'],
            :supervisorEmail => u['SUPERVISOR_EMAIL']
        }
        @service = Service.new(monkey)
    else
        @service = Service.new
    end
  end
```

As you can see the params[:provider] is passed directly to the OCI8 query:

```
def findByUserName(id)
    if id
        cursor = cursor_exec("SELECT DISTINCT 
                    <QUERY INFO HERE>
            AND external_user = :id
            ORDER BY last_name, first_name", id)
        collection = cursor.fetch_hash()
        cursor.close
        logoff
        collection
    end
end
```

Cursor_exec function

```
def cursor_exec(sql, *params)
  @conn = OCI8.new('user','pass','server')
  if params.length > 0
    cursor = @conn.exec(sql, *params)
  else
    cursor = @conn.exec(sql)
  end 
end
```

Will OCI8 properly sanitize the parameter through the bind or is there a method I can use to be more safe?

Comment: I can't find docs on `cursor_exec()` (I can find `cursor.exec()`), but if it is in fact creating a prepared statement as it appears to be, then this isn't vulnerable.

Comment: @Michael yes, cursor_exec is defined at the beginning of our file and uses .exec to build the query like so `cursor = @conn.exec(query,params)`

Comment: So does your `cursor_exec()` function actually call `bind_param()` on the input params or just do some string substitution on them?

Comment: @Michael I've edited the question to show you the cursor_exec function. The reason its defined such is that we have multiple queries for different uses. Some of them have parameters and some do not, this was one way we could use one connection without having to redefine it for each instance.

Comment: See below -- you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are internally calling `OCI8#exec()`, the second parameter passed to it will be bound as a parameter to the query, you needn't worry about additional escaping. It should be protected internally by the `exec()` call.

[From the docs:](http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/api_OCI8.html)

> #### exec(sql, *bindvars)
>
> execute the sql statement. The type of return value depends on the type of sql statement: select; insert, update and delete; create, alter and drop; and PL/SQL.
>
> When bindvars are specified, they are bound as bind variables before execution.

Comment: What about table names, and other identifiers that aren't supported by bind vars?

Comment: @Alexander If you are using dynamic table or identifier names, you should validate them against a list of acceptable possible values before passing them into the SQL (because tables and columns etc are always known in advance anyway).  Create an array of possible values for the identifier then check if your input value is in the array.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing, but I'd rather put in the stripping logic as an extra fail-safe against future erroneous edits in table name array